# Supervisord log file rotation settings

Tags: php, centos, supervisord

I have started some php processes with supervisord, and i am keeping all the stdout logs on one file and the error output on an other one. I have set the max size at 1mb and i am running 3 copies of each process. When i check the logs there appears to be more than one  of the log files, so instead of "`log1.log`" there is "`log1.log log1.log.1 log1.log.2 log1.log.3`". The process seems to work correctly so i am just asking for clarification, does this happen because the log is locked for writing by an other process so the process that tries to write has to use an other file?

```
[program:Sitbot1_1_1]
command=/usr/local/bin/php -f process.php 1 1 1 2           ; the program (relative uses PATH, can take args)
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d ; process_name expr (default %(program_name)s)
numprocs=3                    ; number of processes copies to start (def 1)
directory=/home/userkdo/domains/domain/public_html/bot1                ; directory to cwd to before exec (def no cwd)
;umask=022                     ; umask for process (default None)
;priority=999                  ; the relative start priority (default 999)
autostart=false                ; start at supervisord start (default: true)
autorestart=true        ; whether/when to restart (default: unexpected)
;startsecs=1                   ; number of secs prog must stay running (def. 1)
;startretries=3                ; max # of serial start failures (default 3)
;exitcodes=0,2                 ; 'expected' exit codes for process (default 0,2)
;stopsignal=TERM               ; signal used to kill process (default TERM)
;stopwaitsecs=10               ; max num secs to wait b4 SIGKILL (default 10)
;stopasgroup=true             ; send stop signal to the UNIX process group (default false)
;killasgroup=true             ; SIGKILL the UNIX process group (def false)
user=userkdo                   ; setuid to this UNIX account to run the program
;redirect_stderr=true          ; redirect proc stderr to stdout (default false)
stdout_logfile=/home/userkdo/domains/domain/public_html/bot1/log/log1.log        ; stdout log path, NONE for none; default AUTO
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=1MB   ; max # logfile bytes b4 rotation (default 50MB)
;stdout_logfile_backups=10     ; # of stdout logfile backups (default 10)
;stdout_capture_maxbytes=1MB   ; number of bytes in 'capturemode' (default 0)
;stdout_events_enabled=false   ; emit events on stdout writes (default false)
stderr_logfile=/home/userkdo/domains/domain/public_html/bot1/log/log1.err        ; stderr log path, NONE for none; default AUTO
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=1MB   ; max # logfile bytes b4 rotation (default 50MB)
;stderr_logfile_backups=10     ; # of stderr logfile backups (default 10)
;stderr_capture_maxbytes=1MB   ; number of bytes in 'capturemode' (default 0)
;stderr_events_enabled=false   ; emit events on stderr writes (default false)
;environment=A="1",B="2"       ; process environment additions (def no adds)
;serverurl=AUTO                ; override serverurl computation (childutils)





[program:Sitbot1_1_2]
command=/usr/local/bin/php -f process.php 1 2 3 4           ; the program (relative uses PATH, can take args)
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d ; process_name expr (default %(program_name)s)
numprocs=3                    ; number of processes copies to start (def 1)
directory=/home/userkdo/domains/domain/public_html/bot1                ; directory to cwd to before exec (def no cwd)
;umask=022                     ; umask for process (default None)
;priority=999                  ; the relative start priority (default 999)
autostart=false                ; start at supervisord start (default: true)
autorestart=true        ; whether/when to restart (default: unexpected)
;startsecs=1                   ; number of secs prog must stay running (def. 1)
;startretries=3                ; max # of serial start failures (default 3)
;exitcodes=0,2                 ; 'expected' exit codes for process (default 0,2)
;stopsignal=TERM               ; signal used to kill process (default TERM)
;stopwaitsecs=10               ; max num secs to wait b4 SIGKILL (default 10)
;stopasgroup=true             ; send stop signal to the UNIX process group (default false)
;killasgroup=true             ; SIGKILL the UNIX process group (def false)
user=userkdo                   ; setuid to this UNIX account to run the program
;redirect_stderr=true          ; redirect proc stderr to stdout (default false)
stdout_logfile=/home/userkdo/domains/domain/public_html/bot1/log/log1.log        ; stdout log path, NONE for none; default AUTO
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=1MB   ; max # logfile bytes b4 rotation (default 50MB)
;stdout_logfile_backups=10     ; # of stdout logfile backups (default 10)
;stdout_capture_maxbytes=1MB   ; number of bytes in 'capturemode' (default 0)
;stdout_events_enabled=false   ; emit events on stdout writes (default false)
stderr_logfile=/home/userkdo/domains/domain/public_html/bot1/log/log1.err        ; stderr log path, NONE for none; default AUTO
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=1MB   ; max # logfile bytes b4 rotation (default 50MB)
;stderr_logfile_backups=10     ; # of stderr logfile backups (default 10)
;stderr_capture_maxbytes=1MB   ; number of bytes in 'capturemode' (default 0)
;stderr_events_enabled=false   ; emit events on stderr writes (default false)
;environment=A="1",B="2"       ; process environment additions (def no adds)
;serverurl=AUTO                ; override serverurl computation (childutils)





[program:Sitbot1_1_3]
command=/usr/local/bin/php -f process.php 1 3 5 6           ; the program (relative uses PATH, can take args)
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d ; process_name expr (default %(program_name)s)
numprocs=3                    ; number of processes copies to start (def 1)
directory=/home/userkdo/domains/domain/public_html/bot1                ; directory to cwd to before exec (def no cwd)
;umask=022                     ; umask for process (default None)
;priority=999                  ; the relative start priority (default 999)
autostart=false                ; start at supervisord start (default: true)
autorestart=true        ; whether/when to restart (default: unexpected)
;startsecs=1                   ; number of secs prog must stay running (def. 1)
;startretries=3                ; max # of serial start failures (default 3)
;exitcodes=0,2                 ; 'expected' exit codes for process (default 0,2)
;stopsignal=TERM               ; signal used to kill process (default TERM)
;stopwaitsecs=10               ; max num secs to wait b4 SIGKILL (default 10)
;stopasgroup=true             ; send stop signal to the UNIX process group (default false)
;killasgroup=true             ; SIGKILL the UNIX process group (def false)
user=userkdo                   ; setuid to this UNIX account to run the program
;redirect_stderr=true          ; redirect proc stderr to stdout (default false)
stdout_logfile=/home/userkdo/domains/domain/public_html/bot1/log/log1.log        ; stdout log path, NONE for none; default AUTO
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=1MB   ; max # logfile bytes b4 rotation (default 50MB)
;stdout_logfile_backups=10     ; # of stdout logfile backups (default 10)
;stdout_capture_maxbytes=1MB   ; number of bytes in 'capturemode' (default 0)
;stdout_events_enabled=false   ; emit events on stdout writes (default false)
stderr_logfile=/home/userkdo/domains/domain/public_html/bot1/log/log1.err        ; stderr log path, NONE for none; default AUTO
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=1MB   ; max # logfile bytes b4 rotation (default 50MB)
;stderr_logfile_backups=10     ; # of stderr logfile backups (default 10)
;stderr_capture_maxbytes=1MB   ; number of bytes in 'capturemode' (default 0)
;stderr_events_enabled=false   ; emit events on stderr writes (default false)
;environment=A="1",B="2"       ; process environment additions (def no adds)
;serverurl=AUTO                ; override serverurl computation (childutils)





[program:Sitbot1_1_4]
command=/usr/local/bin/php -f process.php 1 4 7 9           ; the program (relative uses PATH, can take args)
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d ; process_name expr (default %(program_name)s)
numprocs=3                    ; number of processes copies to start (def 1)
directory=/home/userkdo/domains/domain/public_html/bot1                ; directory to cwd to before exec (def no cwd)
;umask=022                     ; umask for process (default None)
;priority=999                  ; the relative start priority (default 999)
autostart=false                ; start at supervisord start (default: true)
autorestart=true        ; whether/when to restart (default: unexpected)
;startsecs=1                   ; number of secs prog must stay running (def. 1)
;startretries=3                ; max # of serial start failures (default 3)
;exitcodes=0,2                 ; 'expected' exit codes for process (default 0,2)
;stopsignal=TERM               ; signal used to kill process (default TERM)
;stopwaitsecs=10               ; max num secs to wait b4 SIGKILL (default 10)
;stopasgroup=true             ; send stop signal to the UNIX process group (default false)
;killasgroup=true             ; SIGKILL the UNIX process group (def false)
user=userkdo                   ; setuid to this UNIX account to run the program
;redirect_stderr=true          ; redirect proc stderr to stdout (default false)
stdout_logfile=/home/userkdo/domains/domain/public_html/bot1/log/log1.log        ; stdout log path, NONE for none; default AUTO
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=1MB   ; max # logfile bytes b4 rotation (default 50MB)
;stdout_logfile_backups=10     ; # of stdout logfile backups (default 10)
;stdout_capture_maxbytes=1MB   ; number of bytes in 'capturemode' (default 0)
;stdout_events_enabled=false   ; emit events on stdout writes (default false)
stderr_logfile=/home/userkdo/domains/domain/public_html/bot1/log/log1.err        ; stderr log path, NONE for none; default AUTO
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=1MB   ; max # logfile bytes b4 rotation (default 50MB)
;stderr_logfile_backups=10     ; # of stderr logfile backups (default 10)
;stderr_capture_maxbytes=1MB   ; number of bytes in 'capturemode' (default 0)
;stderr_events_enabled=false   ; emit events on stderr writes (default false)
;environment=A="1",B="2"       ; process environment additions (def no adds)
;serverurl=AUTO                ; override serverurl computation (childutils)





[program:Sitbot1_1_5]
command=/usr/local/bin/php -f process.php 1 5 10 12           ; the program (relative uses PATH, can take args)
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d ; process_name expr (default %(program_name)s)
numprocs=3                    ; number of processes copies to start (def 1)
directory=/home/userkdo/domains/domain/public_html/bot1                ; directory to cwd to before exec (def no cwd)
;umask=022                     ; umask for process (default None)
;priority=999                  ; the relative start priority (default 999)
autostart=false                ; start at supervisord start (default: true)
autorestart=true        ; whether/when to restart (default: unexpected)
;startsecs=1                   ; number of secs prog must stay running (def. 1)
;startretries=3                ; max # of serial start failures (default 3)
;exitcodes=0,2                 ; 'expected' exit codes for process (default 0,2)
;stopsignal=TERM               ; signal used to kill process (default TERM)
;stopwaitsecs=10               ; max num secs to wait b4 SIGKILL (default 10)
;stopasgroup=true             ; send stop signal to the UNIX process group (default false)
;killasgroup=true             ; SIGKILL the UNIX process group (def false)
user=userkdo                   ; setuid to this UNIX account to run the program
;redirect_stderr=true          ; redirect proc stderr to stdout (default false)
stdout_logfile=/home/userkdo/domains/domain/public_html/bot1/log/log1.log        ; stdout log path, NONE for none; default AUTO
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=1MB   ; max # logfile bytes b4 rotation (default 50MB)
;stdout_logfile_backups=10     ; # of stdout logfile backups (default 10)
;stdout_capture_maxbytes=1MB   ; number of bytes in 'capturemode' (default 0)
;stdout_events_enabled=false   ; emit events on stdout writes (default false)
stderr_logfile=/home/userkdo/domains/domain/public_html/bot1/log/log1.err        ; stderr log path, NONE for none; default AUTO
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=1MB   ; max # logfile bytes b4 rotation (default 50MB)
;stderr_logfile_backups=10     ; # of stderr logfile backups (default 10)
;stderr_capture_maxbytes=1MB   ; number of bytes in 'capturemode' (default 0)
;stderr_events_enabled=false   ; emit events on stderr writes (default false)
;environment=A="1",B="2"       ; process environment additions (def no adds)
;serverurl=AUTO                ; override serverurl computation (childutils)





[program:Sitbot1_1_6]
command=/usr/local/bin/php -f process.php 1 6 13 15           ; the program (relative uses PATH, can take args)
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d ; process_name expr (default %(program_name)s)
numprocs=3                    ; number of processes copies to start (def 1)
directory=/home/userkdo/domains/domain/public_html/bot1                ; directory to cwd to before exec (def no cwd)
;umask=022                     ; umask for process (default None)
;priority=999                  ; the relative start priority (default 999)
autostart=false                ; start at supervisord start (default: true)
autorestart=true        ; whether/when to restart (default: unexpected)
;startsecs=1                   ; number of secs prog must stay running (def. 1)
;startretries=3                ; max # of serial start failures (default 3)
;exitcodes=0,2                 ; 'expected' exit codes for process (default 0,2)
;stopsignal=TERM               ; signal used to kill process (default TERM)
;stopwaitsecs=10               ; max num secs to wait b4 SIGKILL (default 10)
;stopasgroup=true             ; send stop signal to the UNIX process group (default false)
;killasgroup=true             ; SIGKILL the UNIX process group (def false)
user=userkdo                   ; setuid to this UNIX account to run the program
;redirect_stderr=true          ; redirect proc stderr to stdout (default false)
stdout_logfile=/home/userkdo/domains/domain/public_html/bot1/log/log1.log        ; stdout log path, NONE for none; default AUTO
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=1MB   ; max # logfile bytes b4 rotation (default 50MB)
;stdout_logfile_backups=10     ; # of stdout logfile backups (default 10)
;stdout_capture_maxbytes=1MB   ; number of bytes in 'capturemode' (default 0)
;stdout_events_enabled=false   ; emit events on stdout writes (default false)
stderr_logfile=/home/userkdo/domains/domain/public_html/bot1/log/log1.err        ; stderr log path, NONE for none; default AUTO
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=1MB   ; max # logfile bytes b4 rotation (default 50MB)
;stderr_logfile_backups=10     ; # of stderr logfile backups (default 10)
;stderr_capture_maxbytes=1MB   ; number of bytes in 'capturemode' (default 0)
;stderr_events_enabled=false   ; emit events on stderr writes (default false)
;environment=A="1",B="2"       ; process environment additions (def no adds)
;serverurl=AUTO                ; override serverurl computation (childutils)





[program:Sitbot1_1_7]
command=/usr/local/bin/php -f process.php 1 7 16 18           ; the program (relative uses PATH, can take args)
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d ; process_name expr (default %(program_name)s)
numprocs=3                    ; number of processes copies to start (def 1)
directory=/home/userkdo/domains/domain/public_html/bot1                ; directory to cwd to before exec (def no cwd)
;umask=022                     ; umask for process (default None)
;priority=999                  ; the relative start priority (default 999)
autostart=false                ; start at supervisord start (default: true)
autorestart=true        ; whether/when to restart (default: unexpected)
;startsecs=1                   ; number of secs prog must stay running (def. 1)
;startretries=3                ; max # of serial start failures (default 3)
;exitcodes=0,2                 ; 'expected' exit codes for process (default 0,2)
;stopsignal=TERM               ; signal used to kill process (default TERM)
;stopwaitsecs=10               ; max num secs to wait b4 SIGKILL (default 10)
;stopasgroup=true             ; send stop signal to the UNIX process group (default false)
;killasgroup=true             ; SIGKILL the UNIX process group (def false)
user=userkdo                   ; setuid to this UNIX account to run the program
;redirect_stderr=true          ; redirect proc stderr to stdout (default false)
stdout_logfile=/home/userkdo/domains/domain/public_html/bot1/log/log1.log        ; stdout log path, NONE for none; default AUTO
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=1MB   ; max # logfile bytes b4 rotation (default 50MB)
;stdout_logfile_backups=10     ; # of stdout logfile backups (default 10)
;stdout_capture_maxbytes=1MB   ; number of bytes in 'capturemode' (default 0)
;stdout_events_enabled=false   ; emit events on stdout writes (default false)
stderr_logfile=/home/userkdo/domains/domain/public_html/bot1/log/log1.err        ; stderr log path, NONE for none; default AUTO
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=1MB   ; max # logfile bytes b4 rotation (default 50MB)
;stderr_logfile_backups=10     ; # of stderr logfile backups (default 10)
;stderr_capture_maxbytes=1MB   ; number of bytes in 'capturemode' (default 0)
;stderr_events_enabled=false   ; emit events on stderr writes (default false)
;environment=A="1",B="2"       ; process environment additions (def no adds)
;serverurl=AUTO                ; override serverurl computation (childutils)





[program:Sitbot1_1_8]
command=/usr/local/bin/php -f process.php 1 8 19 22           ; the program (relative uses PATH, can take args)
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d ; process_name expr (default %(program_name)s)
numprocs=3                    ; number of processes copies to start (def 1)
directory=/home/userkdo/domains/domain/public_html/bot1                ; directory to cwd to before exec (def no cwd)
;umask=022                     ; umask for process (default None)
;priority=999                  ; the relative start priority (default 999)
autostart=false                ; start at supervisord start (default: true)
autorestart=true        ; whether/when to restart (default: unexpected)
;startsecs=1                   ; number of secs prog must stay running (def. 1)
;startretries=3                ; max # of serial start failures (default 3)
;exitcodes=0,2                 ; 'expected' exit codes for process (default 0,2)
;stopsignal=TERM               ; signal used to kill process (default TERM)
;stopwaitsecs=10               ; max num secs to wait b4 SIGKILL (default 10)
;stopasgroup=true             ; send stop signal to the UNIX process group (default false)
;killasgroup=true             ; SIGKILL the UNIX process group (def false)
user=userkdo                   ; setuid to this UNIX account to run the program
;redirect_stderr=true          ; redirect proc stderr to stdout (default false)
stdout_logfile=/home/userkdo/domains/domain/public_html/bot1/log/log1.log        ; stdout log path, NONE for none; default AUTO
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=1MB   ; max # logfile bytes b4 rotation (default 50MB)
;stdout_logfile_backups=10     ; # of stdout logfile backups (default 10)
;stdout_capture_maxbytes=1MB   ; number of bytes in 'capturemode' (default 0)
;stdout_events_enabled=false   ; emit events on stdout writes (default false)
stderr_logfile=/home/userkdo/domains/domain/public_html/bot1/log/log1.err        ; stderr log path, NONE for none; default AUTO
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=1MB   ; max # logfile bytes b4 rotation (default 50MB)
;stderr_logfile_backups=10     ; # of stderr logfile backups (default 10)
;stderr_capture_maxbytes=1MB   ; number of bytes in 'capturemode' (default 0)
;stderr_events_enabled=false   ; emit events on stderr writes (default false)
;environment=A="1",B="2"       ; process environment additions (def no adds)
;serverurl=AUTO                ; override serverurl computation (childutils)





[program:Sitbot1_1_9]
command=/usr/local/bin/php -f process.php 1 9 23 26           ; the program (relative uses PATH, can take args)
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d ; process_name expr (default %(program_name)s)
numprocs=3                    ; number of processes copies to start (def 1)
directory=/home/userkdo/domains/domain/public_html/bot1                ; directory to cwd to before exec (def no cwd)
;umask=022                     ; umask for process (default None)
;priority=999                  ; the relative start priority (default 999)
autostart=false                ; start at supervisord start (default: true)
autorestart=true        ; whether/when to restart (default: unexpected)
;startsecs=1                   ; number of secs prog must stay running (def. 1)
;startretries=3                ; max # of serial start failures (default 3)
;exitcodes=0,2                 ; 'expected' exit codes for process (default 0,2)
;stopsignal=TERM               ; signal used to kill process (default TERM)
;stopwaitsecs=10               ; max num secs to wait b4 SIGKILL (default 10)
;stopasgroup=true             ; send stop signal to the UNIX process group (default false)
;killasgroup=true             ; SIGKILL the UNIX process group (def false)
user=userkdo                   ; setuid to this UNIX account to run the program
;redirect_stderr=true          ; redirect proc stderr to stdout (default false)
stdout_logfile=/home/userkdo/domains/domain/public_html/bot1/log/log1.log        ; stdout log path, NONE for none; default AUTO
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=1MB   ; max # logfile bytes b4 rotation (default 50MB)
;stdout_logfile_backups=10     ; # of stdout logfile backups (default 10)
;stdout_capture_maxbytes=1MB   ; number of bytes in 'capturemode' (default 0)
;stdout_events_enabled=false   ; emit events on stdout writes (default false)
stderr_logfile=/home/userkdo/domains/domain/public_html/bot1/log/log1.err        ; stderr log path, NONE for none; default AUTO
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=1MB   ; max # logfile bytes b4 rotation (default 50MB)
;stderr_logfile_backups=10     ; # of stderr logfile backups (default 10)
;stderr_capture_maxbytes=1MB   ; number of bytes in 'capturemode' (default 0)
;stderr_events_enabled=false   ; emit events on stderr writes (default false)
;environment=A="1",B="2"       ; process environment additions (def no adds)
;serverurl=AUTO                ; override serverurl computation (childutils)
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This effect is called **[log rotation](http://supervisord.org/logging.html#activity-log-rotation)**. When log file is bigger than value in `stdout_logfile_maxbytes` it's content is moved to logfile.log.1 for backup. If you want to change this behaviour you can:

- Change value of `stdout_logfile_maxbytes` to 0 - all logs will be kept in one log file.
- Change value of `stdout_logfile_backups` to 0 - when log file is too big old logs will be deleted instead of moved to separate file.

The same applies accordingly to `stderr_logfile_maxbytes` and `stderr_logfile_backups`.

Comment: Yep that sounds like whats happening thnx.

Comment: @daniula Is there a default stdout_logfile_maxbytes if I don't set this value??

Comment: @tyan According to [documentation](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#program-x-section-values) default  value for `stdout_logfile_maxbytes` is 50MB.